# Can a lease contract be voided due to incongruency?

Tags: rental-property

I've recently rented a flat in Malta and signed a rental agreement which states, prior to the terms, I am the landlord and he (the landlord) is the tenant.
By the last page at the bottom, he signed as the landlord and I signed as the tenant.

Would this contract be invalid due to the incongruity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would this contract be invalid due to the incongruity?

No. In case of disputes, it will be easy to establish that the switch of labels was a mere and harmless mistake incapable of *reasonably* confusing either party as to each one's role in the contract. As such, the incongruity is inconsequential to the legal relation between the true landlord and true tenant.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information Iñaki, much appreciated!